# Autodesk viewer fails with 504 (Gateway Timeout) time and again for a file

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm getting this error **504 (Gateway Timeout) 6** time and again while trying to view a file. It's weird that this doesn't happen always, the viewer gets rendered as usual but sometimes we get this error.

Previously I thought it was rather a cache or connection issue. But this happens even when we have a stable internet connection. And sometimes it persists even after doing hard refresh multiple times. So, it's weird.

**I just want to know reason why this error actually occurs.**

We're using viewer version `v2.8` here.

The viewer renders this message:

[image]

And here is the exact error message we get in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell what's wrong without some code to look at...

But it seems that you are using V1 and would recommend you migrate to V2. See [this blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/autodesk-forge-apis-migrating-from-v1-to-v2.html) with more details on the migrations. There are several benefits! :-)

Also, consider using the latest viewer version, [2.10](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.10/) (as of September, 2016).

Comment: Actually, we're already using the new `v2` model derivative and data management APIs as shown in the blog post. But, upgrading the viewer to  `v2.10` seems to have solved some issues so, I think this issue is solved as well.